# Remove Web.config Setting programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-config

Having trouble on removing Web.config settings programmatically I tried [this msdn code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861909.aspx) (using both SPWebService and SPWebApplication) hoping it would work but although the adding works, the remove doesn´t seem to work.

I'm using the Add on a feature Activated method and the remove on a feature deactivated and the feature has WebApplication Scope.

I've tried the mentioned script but the result stayed the same.

Is there some necessary setting that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried it will help others to assist you

Comment: also please post what exactly doesnt work.. any exceptions?

Comment: @MLF I didn't post any code because I was using the exact code on that msdn link, maybe I should have posted anyway, yes.

Comment: @Andreas Scharf No exception, just the setting is not removed from the file but is also not added a second time.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may be interested, I got it working like this:

Instead of doing the remove and update outside the for cycle like the msdn code I do it inside:

```
int modsCount1 = modsCollection.Count;
for (int i = modsCount1 - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    if (modsCollection[i].Owner == "User Name")
    {
        configModFound = modsCollection[i];
    }
    // Remove it and save the change to the configuration database  
    modsCollection.Remove(configModFound);
    webApplication.Update();
}
```